# Как сделать многоуровневую клавиатуру для бота на Aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Я хотел бы сделать так, что бы при старте давалась клавиатура с кнопками (к примеру) "Нормально" и "Не очень", и бот писал как твоё настроение.
После этого он должен в случае нажатия кнопки "Нормально" написать отлично и дать другую клавиатуру, так же и с кнопкой "Не очень"

Answer (score -1):

Если я правильно все понял, то все довольно просто: отлавливаешь команду start и в callback отправляешь сообщение и к нему приделываешь нужную inline  клавиатуру. А в callback клавиатуры снова отправляешь сообщение и к нему приделываешь другую inline клавиатуру. Как-то так:

```
 from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor

from aiogram.types import CallbackQuery, Message,\
    InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup

import asyncio

bot=Bot("Здесь твой токен")
dp=Dispatcher(bot)

#Создание первой  клавиатуры
how_are_you_kb=InlineKeyboardMarkup().row(
    InlineKeyboardButton(text="нормально",callback_data="good"),
    InlineKeyboardButton(text="не очень",callback_data="bad"))

#Указываем что сделать при нажатии на кнопку,
#в нашем случаи прислать другую клавиатуру
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'good')
async def callback(message: Message):
    await bot.send_message(
        chat_id=message.from_user.id,
        reply_markup=feel_good_kb,
        text="отлично")

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'bad')
async def callback(message: Message):
    await bot.send_message(
        chat_id=message.from_user.id,
        reply_markup=fell_bad_kb,
        text="плохо")

#Снова создаем клавиатуры
#сallback добавишь сам
feel_good_kb=InlineKeyboardMarkup().row(
    InlineKeyboardButton(
        text="радость",
        callback_data="feel_good"))

fell_bad_kb=InlineKeyboardMarkup().row(
    InlineKeyboardButton(
        text="боль",
        callback_data="fell_bad"))


#Здесь отлавливаем команду старт
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def callback_start(message: Message):

    await bot.send_message(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        reply_markup=how_are_you_kb,
        text="как настроение ?")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```